# remove inline style from html body

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to find a solution for this for what should be so simple. Here is the following code I'm doing...

```
  function updateScrollBarWidth() {
    const scrollWidthBefore = Number(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed(2));
    document.body.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
    const scrollWidthAfter = Number(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed(2));
    setScrollBarWidth(scrollWidthBefore - scrollWidthAfter);
    document.body.removeAttribute('style');
    // document.body.style.overflowY = '';
  }
```

The contents in the style get removed, but the style is still left in the element tag like so...

[image]

Instead I would like it to look like this after the function completes...

[image]

Comment: A temporary solution is to replace the `removeAttribute` line with `setTimeout(() => document.body.removeAttribute('style'), 1);`. I am not at all sure why this works, but with just a 1ms delay it removes the style attribute entirely. It did *not* work with a 0ms delay.

Comment: @ConnorMooneyhan Unfortunately this till isn't working. I get the same result without the timeout

Comment: Did you try it with a longer timeout?

Comment: yeah 50 milliseconds seems to be enough. I hate using setTimeouts in production code, but I guess this seems to be the only way to handle this.